# Uniqueness and existence proof - differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good morning,

I have the following problem to solve which I do not understand how to approach.

"Find $C^\infty$ function $h:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ so that the problem $h(y')= y$, $y(0) = 0$ does not have a solution."

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Please use Latex and show us what you have done/the point where you are stuck at

Comment: I do not know how to approach the problem in order to start solving. That's why I'm asking in order to get a hint on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $h(y'(0))=y(0)=0$. Can you contradict this by choosing a specific $h$?

Comment: Solved it thank you very much! :)